# How to use style from another resource in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to change ScrollBar in my particular ListBox control. I have a ScrollBar style in another resource. But I don't know how to apply it. For example, I can apply a template from another resource, like this:

```
<ListBox
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType = "ScrollBar">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MyScbTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

But I can't do the same with Style, like this:

```
<Style TargetType = "ScrollBar">
 <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource MyScbStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: @Mike Eason, that's was really helpful for me, thanks you! Unfortunatelly it throws an error when I use DynamicResource, but if I use StaticResource it works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right lines, you can't set the Style's Style inside the Style. (Yep.)

Instead, you need to **inherit** the *parent* style, like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar" BasedOn="{DynamicResource MyScbStyle}">
```

For some more reading on `BasedOn`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx).